# wxWidgets with GUI with javascript interacting with C++

Tags: javascript, html, c++, wxwidgets

I am experimenting with wxWidget where the view is an html file with a simple button for now and I want when the button is pressed that a C++ function will be called.  I have tried a bunch of things and nothing has been working.  I added in my html code and C++ code here.  If I click the button I do not see the function OnWebViewNavigating in C++ code getting called.

Some suggestions where to use wxEVT_WEBVIEW_SCRIPT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, I have modified the code below to show that but still seeing same behavior.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Local WebView</title>
    <script>
        function callCppFunction() {
            // Use the postMessage API to communicate with the host (wxWidgets)
            window.cppHandler.postMessage('cppFunction', '*');
        }
        
        // Attach the event listener to the button
        var cppFunctionButton = document.getElementById('cppFunctionButton');
        cppFunctionButton.addEventListener('click', callCppFunction);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="cppFunctionButton">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

c++ wxWidget code

```
 #include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/webview.h>

class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
        : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
    {
        wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

        webview = wxWebView::New(this, wxID_ANY);
        sizer->Add(webview, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5);

        SetSizerAndFit(sizer);

        // Load the local index.html file
        webview->LoadURL("file:///C:/index.html");

        // Set up a script message handler
        webview->AddScriptMessageHandler("cppHandler");

        // Bind the custom event from JavaScript to a C++ function
        webview->Bind(wxEVT_WEBVIEW_SCRIPT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, &MyFrame::OnScriptMessageReceived, this);
    }

private:
    wxWebView* webview;

    void OnScriptMessageReceived(wxWebViewEvent& event)
    {
        wxString message = event.GetString();

        if (message == "cppFunction")
        {
            // Call your C++ function here
            wxMessageBox("C++ function called successfully", "Message", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION);
        }
    }
};

class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit()
    {
        wxInitAllImageHandlers();
        MyFrame* frame = new MyFrame(wxT("wxWebView Example"), wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 600));
        frame->Show(true);
        return true;
    }
};

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/classwx_web_view.html#a2597c3371ed654bf03262ec6d34a0126

Comment: thank you for the pointer, I tried adding the wxEVT_WEBVIEW_SCRIPT_MESSAGE_RECEIVED binding but seeing the same behavior where the function is not being called.

Comment: Are you sure `OnScriptMessageReceived` isn't being called? It's not just that `message != "cppFunction"`?

Comment: @Godspped, what wx version do you use? What platform? What backend? Can you run the webview sample?

Comment: I am using wxWidgets version 3.2.4, I am seeing what backend is being used, I built wxWidgets through cmake but didnt get an option of building for edge or to select a backend.

Comment: In the javascript code, there won't be an element with the id "cppFunctionButton" at the time the script is run.  You can either define the button something like <button id="cppFunctionButton" onclick="callCppFunction()"... or move the script block to the end of the body element.

Comment: I confirmed its using the Edge, I found the enable in CMake in the advance settings of the GUI and enabled it and confirmed the sample web example is using edge, as well as the sample above is also using edge.  To test it I added in a #ifdef wxUSE_WEBVIEW_EDGE to see if a message box comes up and I confirmed it did.  But still my callback isnt triggering.

Comment: I also tried changing the button as well as moving the script block to the end but that also didnt help :(

Comment: @Godspped, see if `New Pagodi` suggestion helps. Also check if webview sample works for you.

Comment: The current [documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html#a2597c3371ed654bf03262ec6d34a0126) says "The Edge backend only supports a single message handler and the IE backend does not support script message handlers." so I guess if your using edge, you'll need to fall back to the older way of using the wxEVT_WEBVIEW_NAVIGATING event to send information from javascript to c++.

Comment: thank you! I was able to get things to work, I found the webviewsample has #ifdef's for wxUSE_WEBVIEW_EDGE which sets a bunch of edge related handlers.  After adding that the AddScriptMessageHandler stopped erroring out.  Thank you for all of the suggestions they greatly helped.

Comment: @Godspped, you should ALWAYS start with official sample code, no matter what library you are working with...

Comment: And of course there are not just webview one in wx. BTW,  soon there will be Chromium backend in wx...